# Control overflow of TD element

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I have got TD with long text in it. I'd like it to be ellipsised, but I don't want to define the absolute width of this column - I want it to be calculated dynamically by its parent table. Is it possible? Here is a code for example:

```
<table width="100%" border="3">
<tr>
<td ><span style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; 
 text-overflow: ellipsis;" >
Here should be very long text: 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
</span></td>
</table>
```

Is there any way to force IE browser to display ellipsis even without defining the 'span' element with absolute width for example: width=300px ?

Comment: Are you willing to use some JavaScript?

Comment: BTW - in the example above even when changing the width of the table to be absolute (for example width=900px) it won't change anything and the size of the table will exceed the screen size due to the length of the cell's text

Comment: regarding javascript - if you have a suggestion, go ahead but basically I'd rather a solution that is based on CSS and HTML layout definitions

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The best answer I found:
wrapping the long content of the TD in table with the definition: 
 '**table-layout: fixed**'  This will magically solve this issue. 
 
See for yourself -

```
<table width="100%" border="3">
<tr> <td>
<TABLE width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style='table-layout:fixed'><TR>
<TD style='text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>
Here should be very long text: 
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
</TD></TR></TABLE>
</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another way works without **table-layout: fixed.**

Put your context into an td using input **Value** or **Placeholder** attribute.

Then Style the input Like a normal context can't be edit.

This will works with a true flexible table td width.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="TitleTitleTitleTitle" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="ValueValueValueValue" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="NumberNumberNumberNumber" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<style>
table{
  width: 100%;
}
td{
  input{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

No! IE does not allow changing the way the table is displayed, so if you don't use an element like a span the text won't clipped. If you need put ellipsis to clip the text you must use an element like a span or div with absolute width.

To turn it automatically you can use JavaScript or switch from table to div's.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: That's ridiculous - since if I remove the attribute 'white-space: nowrap' IE know to consider the table's width and to wrap the text accordingly. so why can't it do the same in case the text should be clipped? But you may be right - IE behave strangely sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `-ms-text-overflow`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531174(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Isn't it part of .NET framework only? in any case I don't see how it helps to solve this use case.

Comment: Nope.  The -ms-text-overflow attribute is an extension to CSS, and can be be used in IE8 mode.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using jQuery...

Note: "text-overflow: ellipsis" doesn't seem to be working in FF4.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vgfDd/1/

```
$w = $('.setWidth').attr('width');
$('.setWidth').find('span').width($w);
```

CSS...

```
table {
    border: 3px solid black;
}

span {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

HTML...

```
<table width="100px" class="setWidth">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>
                Here should be very long text: 
                bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>
                Here should be very long text: 
                bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure CSS and JavaScript (no jQuery needed) solution is outlined here: http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2007/08/ellipsis-or-truncate-with-dots-via-javascript

But you'll need to wrap the content per Vismari's comment above.

Answer (score -4):

You should use `<table width="inherit">` for it to inherit its width from the parent element.

Comment: Aha! Thank you ilmari; in the future, @Inyavic, please surround any HTML tags with backticks (`) so that they appear in the text. Without that, all context was missing.